# Disable button trigger until animate finish (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['slots']);
 myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.btnTrigger = false;
    $scope.btnClick = function () {
        $scope.btnTrigger = true;
    };
});

angular.module('slots', []).directive('slot', function () {
    var spin = {
        restrict: 'E',
        fn: {
            go: function (num) {
                spin.fn.addSlots(num);
                for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
                (function(i){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    if(i==1){
                        spin.fn.moveSlots($('#slots .wrapper'),num);
                        } else {
                            spin.fn.moveSlots($('#slots .wrapper'+i),num);
                            }
                        }, 200 * i);
                    }(i));
                }
            },
            moveSlots: function (elem,num) {
                if(firstspin==1){
                var marginTop = parseInt(elem.css("margin-top"), 0);
                marginTop -= (num-0.5)*100;

                } else {
                    var marginTop = parseInt(elem.css("margin-top"), 0);
                marginTop -= num*100;
                }
                elem.stop(true,true);
                elem.animate(
                    {"margin-top":marginTop+"px"},
                    {'duration' : 4000, 'easing' : $.bez([0,0,1,1.05]), complete: function(){
                        if(firstspin<=5){
                        elem.children(".slot").slice(0,num-1).remove();
                        firstspin += 1;
                        } else {
                        elem.children(".slot").slice(0,num).remove();
                        }
                        elem.css( "margin-top", -50 );
                    }}
                );
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
            if (attrs.trigger && attrs.trigger !== undefined) {
                if (scope[attrs.trigger] !== undefined) {
                    scope.$watch(attrs.trigger, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                        if (newValue) {
                            spin.fn.go(100);
                            scope.btnTrigger = false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return spin;
});

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <slot trigger="btnTrigger"></slot>
     <button ng-click="btnClick()">Play</button>
</div>
```

It is a slot machine game. How do I prevent user from multiple input until my slot machine has finished its spinning animation? The scope.btnTrigger = false; triggers before the animation even finish.

[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/d9sXgolxZ94936W1FO67?p=preview)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't seem to get it to work on JSFiddle so yeah...

Comment: Can you create plunker demo with full code?

Comment: @shaishabroy i will try

Answer (score 1):

Your could use angular [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service for this. Your code might look like following:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['slots']);
 myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.btnTrigger = false;
    $scope.btnClick = function () {
        $scope.btnTrigger = true;
    };
});

angular.module('slots', [])
    .directive('slot', ['$q',function ($q) {
        var go = function (num) {
                    var promiseList = [];

                    spin.fn.addSlots(num);  //unable to find this function
                    for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){

                        (function(i){
                            var promise = $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    if(i==1){
                                        spin.fn.moveSlots($('#slots .wrapper'),num);
                                    } else {
                                        spin.fn.moveSlots($('#slots .wrapper'+i),num);
                                    }
                                    resolve();
                                }, 200 * i);
                            }
                            promiseList.push(promise;
                        }(i));
                    }
                }
        var spin = {
            restrict: 'E',
            fn: {

                moveSlots: function (elem,num) {
                    if(firstspin==1){
                    var marginTop = parseInt(elem.css("margin-top"), 0);
                    marginTop -= (num-0.5)*100;

                    } else {
                        var marginTop = parseInt(elem.css("margin-top"), 0);
                    marginTop -= num*100;
                    }
                    elem.stop(true,true);
                    elem.animate(
                        {"margin-top":marginTop+"px"},
                        {'duration' : 4000, 'easing' : $.bez([0,0,1,1.05]), complete: function(){
                            if(firstspin<=5){
                            elem.children(".slot").slice(0,num-1).remove();
                            firstspin += 1;
                            } else {
                            elem.children(".slot").slice(0,num).remove();
                            }
                            elem.css( "margin-top", -50 );
                        }}
                    );
                }
            },
            link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                if (attrs.trigger && attrs.trigger !== undefined) {
                    if (scope[attrs.trigger] !== undefined) {
                        scope.$watch(attrs.trigger, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                            if (newValue) {
                                $q.all(go(100))
                                .then(function (){
                                    scope.btnTrigger = false;
                                })

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        return spin;
    });

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <slot trigger="btnTrigger"></slot>
     <button ng-click="btnClick()">Play</button>
</div>
```

This will allow to achieve your task. I have not tested this code, however your solution should be more close to this.. :)

Comment: hmmm using promises huh? alright i will look into it. i'm still new to angularjs. and yeah the addslots function is not here